# ASP.net Override smtp FROM with different FROM addresses in codebehind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a web site where the from mail settings are configured in web.config with

```
<smtp from="xxx@ourdomain.com">
```

One of the pages on the website sends e-mails. This page can only be access by certain members who each have their own e-mail address under the domain setup in web.config.

What I would like to be able to do is change the from address based upon the logged in users e-mail address. The code is setup and works fine with 1 exception, when the to recipient receives the e-mail it is listed as from xxx@ourdomain.com on behalf of someuser@ourdomain.com. What I would like to see is for the recipient to see the from as someruser@domain.com.

Is this specific to our email server (Arvixe) or can this be fixed via code? As an alternate is there a way to programmatically change the web.config smtp FROM setting for the individual user? I have to believe that there is another solution out there than purchasing a third party solution such as aspNetEmail.

Web.config settings:

```
<mailSettings>
  <smtp from="xxx@ourdomain.com">        
    <network host="mail.somehost.com" port="26" userName="xxx@ourdomain.com" password="*****" />
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

Portion of code behind used to send e-mail:

```
        Dim EmailTo As String = item(1).ToString

        Dim objMail As New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
        objMail.Attachments.Add(imgAtt)
        objMail.Subject = ASPxTextBox1.Text.ToString
        objMail.From = New System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("someuser@ourdomain.com")
        objMail.Body = message
        objMail.IsBodyHtml = True

        objMail.To.Clear()
        objMail.To.Add(New System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(EmailTo))
        smtp.Send(objMail)
```

Comment: i have some but im not using web.config for smtp

Comment: No it's not specific to your server. It can be change at runtime. Have you tried anything?